# Сохранение жизни фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

**Что есть:**

У меня в приложении есть BottomNavigationView, в котором находится 3 кнопки, при нажатии на которые идет смена фрагментов в `Activity`.

**Вот таким способом:**

```
 bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id){
                case R.id.action_dialogs:
                    fragment = new DialogsFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_profile:
                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_setting:
                    fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    break;
            }
            transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**Проблема:**

Но при переключении фрагментов они заново пересоздаются. Как это исправить?

**Всем заранее спасибо!**

Comment: "Но при переключении фрагментов они заново пересоздаются. Как это исправить?" А должно быть как-то по-другому? Рекомендую почитать про MVP и Moxy. Пересоздающиеся фрагменты- это best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом простом, но не лучшем варианте, Вы можете просто кэшировать фрагменты, если это необходимо. Просто не создавайте их заново с помощью `new` каждый раз, а сохраните как поля Вашей `Activity` (но так они не переживут поворот девайса) или как синглтоны. Такой метод далёк от идеала, но в зависимости от того, что Вы делаете, можно воспользоваться им как наиболее простым.
В качестве альтернативы [вот тут](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-cache-fragments-in-android-770576e3ab10) ещё человек предлагает их кэшировать в бэк стеке.

Вообще в пересоздании фрагментов нет ничего плохого. В общем случае лучше было бы добавить возможность сохранить введённые данные и пересоздать фрагмент с определённой информацией, оставшейся от предыдущего, например, сохранить введённые данные в базу или `SharedPreferences` и прочитать при инициализации фрагмента или передать в качестве аргументов.